# PDO fetchObject по какому принципу работает

Tags: php

Была зача осуществить подмену значений при вызове `fetchObject`, есть таблица (mysql) у которой один столбец с типом json, думал при создании объекта через `fetchObject` строку json превратить в массив, решения не нашел. Логично вызвать самому объект и заполнить его, конвертируя значения из базы как угодно.

**UPD:**

> Была зача осуществить подмену значений при вызове `fetchObject...

[@LaukhinAndrey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/443096/laukhin-andrey) помог с решением. Однако вопрос ниже актуален

---

Свойства целевого объекта приватные, и вот тут не понимаю как именно работает `fetchObject`, тк в объекте есть методы `__set`, `__clone` и не один из них не срабатывает, и возник вопрос, как `fetchObject` возвращает заполненый класс с приватными свойствами в обход магических методов?

**UPD:**

Вызвал все [методы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php)

```php
class User
{

  private ?string $name = null;
  private ?string $surname = null;
  private ?string $lastname = null;
  private ?string $email = null;
  private int     $phone = 0;
  private ?string $address = null;
  private $time_register = 0;
  private ?string $pass = null;
  private $service = '';

  function __construct(...$arg)
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    var_dump($arg);

    $this->service = json_decode($this->service, true);
  }
  function __destruct()
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
  }
  function __call($arg1, $arg2)
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    var_dump($arg1);
    var_dump($arg2);
  }
  static function __callStatic($arg1, $arg2)
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    var_dump($arg1);
    var_dump($arg2);
  }
  function __get($arg)
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    var_dump($arg);
  }
  function __set($arg1, $arg2)
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    var_dump($arg1);
    var_dump($arg2);
  }
  function __isset($arg)
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    var_dump($arg);
  }
  function __unset($arg)
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    var_dump($arg);
  }
  function __sleep()
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
  }
  function __wakeup()
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
  }
  function __serialize()
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
  }
  function __unserialize()
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
  }
  function __toString()
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
  }
  function __invoke()
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
  }
  function __set_state()
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
  }
  function __clone()
  {
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
  }
}

# ---------------------------------

$PDO = DB::Connect();
$PDOSt = $PDO->query('SELECT * FROM service_users');

var_dump($PDOSt->fetchObject('SCCT\Model\User'));
```

Результат:

```
string(28) "SCCT\Model\User::__construct"
array(0) {
}

object(SCCT\Model\User)#51 (9) {
  ["name":"SCCT\Model\User":private]=>
  string(4) "Jonh"
  ["surname":"SCCT\Model\User":private]=>
  string(3) "Doe"
  ["lastname":"SCCT\Model\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["email":"SCCT\Model\User":private]=>
  string(11) "jd@mail.com"
  ["phone":"SCCT\Model\User":private]=>
  int(71000010203)
  ["address":"SCCT\Model\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["time_register":"SCCT\Model\User":private]=>
  string(19) "2022-05-20 13:36:18"
  ["pass":"SCCT\Model\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["service":"SCCT\Model\User":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["hello"]=>
    string(5) "world"
  }
}

string(27) "SCCT\Model\User::__destruct"
```

Comment: Вы можете передать `fetchObject` в качестве первого аргумента ваш класс, в конструкторе которого преобразовать JSON в массив.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey Так и есть, думал без `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`  конструктор будет первый вызван, думал и не проверил...

Comment: Вызвал все магические методы и сработали только два

Comment: Судя по описаниям, логика такая: Если свойство существует (не важно public или private), то будет присвоено значение, если не существует, то будет вызван __set. Т.е. работает как фильтр на автоматическое создание свойств. Т.е. __set не будет вызван уже для существующего свойства. Обойти это, видимо, невозможно.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey удалил свойство `name` и да был вызван метод  `__set()`, теперь остался один вопрос, какой механизм присвоения значений приватным свойствам вне класса, объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Добавить метод setProperty($prop, $value)?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey вы об этом `ReflectionProperty::setValue`?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey попробовал через `ReflectionProperty::setValue` установить свойство, `__set` молчит, не знал про этот класс. Оформите ответ?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что Вы не хотите делать преобразование в конструкторе, а хотите для каждого полученного из базы объекта сделать это преобразование (для приватного свойства) вне класса?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey да, все так

Comment: А если в User добавить метод prepareProps() и просто вызывать его для каждого полученного объекта? Все же реализация этого внутри каждого класса (со своей внутренней кухней), кажется, правильнее, чем для каждого случая (класса) из вне?

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey и одной стороны да, согласен, но с другой в каждой модели делать метод например `upgradeJSON`, который будет работать одинаково

Comment: Если метод и правда у всех классов одинаковый, то пусть все наследуются от базового с этим методом. Потенциально, в каждой модели могут потребоваться индивидуальные подготовительные действия, тогда надо будет просто переопределить метод. Но тут, естественно, Вам виднее. Просто мысли вслух.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, вы правы, изначально думал часть логики поместить в модели, но ведь по сути, это просто хранилище данных нужным образом отформатированное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Независимо от модификатора доступа, если свойство существует, то будет присвоено значение, если не существует, то будет попытка вызвать магический метод `__set`. Если он не определён, то свойство будет создано.

Таким образом, мы можем определить `__set`, чтобы предотвратить автоматическое создание свойств, но он никогда не будет вызван для существующих свойств.

С учетом того, что свойства закрытые, один из вариантов решения: сделать необходимые преобразования в конструкторе класса, передаваемого в `fetchObject`. Конструктор будет вызван после того, как свойства заполнятся значениями соответствующих столбцов. Это порядок по умолчанию, если не установлен `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`.

Другой подход – предусмотреть метод `prepareProps`, который вызывать при получении очередного объекта из базы.

Изменить приватный метод из вне можно при помощи класса [`ReflectionProperty`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.reflectionproperty.php).